# What would happen if the thread dies unnaturally?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, connection, passenger, pool

We have 8 phusion passengers with 20 connections each. should be 160 max connection. Today our Mysql connection crossed 300 and our server stopped responding.

What would happen if the thread dies unnaturally ? how do db connections associated with it get cleaned-up?

How to debug this type of scenario ?

Comment: What does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` say? You can cross-reference this with the output of `lsof` on each machine to see if they're actually using 20 each. They might be using more.

Answer (score 1):

#### What would happen if the thread dies unnaturally ?

If you are using your statements under transaction then all statements under un-successful transactions will be rolled back but if you are executing your statements individually then how many have been executed will be saved in db but other un-successful will not and data can be in-consistant.

#### how do db connections associated with it get cleaned-up?

As per my assumption your application is opening connections more than required and also not closing properly. In this case if you check connections in mysql admininstrator then you will get so many connections in sleep mode. So you can kill all sleep connections to clean them.

#### How to debug this type of scenario ?

Step1: Enable general logs on your server:

Step2: execute below command in any gui tool like sqlyog etc.

```
show full processlist;
```

Step3: Take first sleep process from above command:

Step3: find/grep above process id (suppose it is 235798) in your general log. You can use below command.

```
$ cat /var/log/mysqldquery.log | grep 235798
```

Note: there can be different file name and path for your general log file.

Above command will show you few lines, check if you are closing connection at the end, should show "quite" statement at the end of line. In this way you need to check few processes those are in sleep mode and you can jugde which type statements/from which module opening extra connectiions and not closing and accordingly you can take action.